# FactoryGirl giving me an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I got this model:

```
rails g model Absence user:references company:references from:date to:date date:date category:integer hours:decimal remarks
```

This also generates:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :absence do
    user nil
    company nil
    from nil
    to nil
    date nil
    category 0
    hours "8.00"
    remarks "MyString"
  end
end
```

I set from, to and date to nil because it's either: from and to OR a certain date.

When I try this in my spec:

```
@absence = create(:absence, user: @company.owner, from: "2015-09-10", to: "2015-09-10", hours: 4)
```

I receive this error message:

```
NoMethodError:
  undefined method `from=' for #<Absence:0x007f81f5494b88>
```

What could be wrong?

Edit:
When I remove the

```
from nil
```

from the factories/absences.rb I'm getting it on the next field (to) and after removing that I'm seeing the error message on category.

Edit2:
Model:

```
class Absence < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :company
  enum type: {holiday: 0, sick: 1} 
  validates :from, presence: true, if: '!user_id.nil?'
  validates :to, presence: true, if: '!user_id.nil?'
  validates :date, presence: true, if: '!company_id.nil?'
  validates :hours, presence: true, if: '!user_id.nil?'
  validates :hours, :numericality => { :greater_than_or_equal_to => 0 }, if: '!user_id.nil?'
  validates :category, presence: true, if: '!user_id.nil?'
  validates_numericality_of :company_id, allow_nil: true
  validates_numericality_of :user_id, allow_nil: true
  validate :company_xor_user 
  validate :to_date_after_from_date
  validate :hours_smaller_than_workday
  validate :non_overlapping
  after_save :calculate_time_checks
  after_destroy :calculate_time_checks_delete
```

DB:
https://www.evernote.com/shard/s29/sh/e8c1429d-9fa7-475b-87e8-3dc11a3f3978/08a7e7d6dfd80c6f407339cab97734c2

Comment: if you just do `@absence = create(:absence, user: @company.owner, to: "2015-09-10", hours: 4)` without the `from`, does it work?

Comment: What's your model look like?

Comment: Can you post your model code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FINALLY found the real cause.

At first I had the Absence model created with an attribute named 'type'.  This was migrated to both the development and test database.  Afterwards I changed it to category and added 'from' and 'to' as well and did a rollback and migrated again (but not on test!).

By using pry

```
require 'pry'; binding.pry
```

in the test I did Absence.columns and noticed the difference.

Comment: You're right in that you shouldn't use a `type` column with `ActiveRecord`, since it's used for Single Table Inheritance (STI): http://benv.ca/2007/01/16/legacy-rails-beware-of-type-columns/. However, that error you got may happen as well if you don't run `rake db:test:prepare` after running a migration.